# AD User provisioning - SOAP API?

Tags: active-directory

I am looking at a scenario wherein we would like to provision (i.e. create) users programmatically into AD from our app. I was wondering if AD offers any kind of SOAP based APIs that can be used for this purpose. 
Anyone have experience / information regarding such a scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ADFS doesn't have any users. Authentication (and "users") are always in Active Directory. There are many APIs to interact with AD. (e.g. [Directory Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.aspx))

I'm not aware of a SOAP based API, but you could build one wrapping the API described above. Also, I would look into whether this is really necessary. If the provisioning engine is meant to be run in the same domain (e.g. on-premises) then you would not need SOAP.